# Bing Truck Routing API - travelDistance units

Tags: bing-maps

We're dipping our toes into the Truck Routing API, and have a question on the units used in the travelDistance element of the regionTravelSummary.

Example GET request

https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/Truck?wayPoint.1=85710&waypoint.2=80634&routeAttributes=regionTravelSummary&distanceUnit=mi&vehicleTrailers=1&key=

What's interesting is in the routeLegs.RegionTravelSummary, the travelDistance is not in Miles (or kilometers, or anything I can figure out). Here's a snippet of the JSON:

```
"regionTravelSummary":[
                        {
                           "name":"United States",
                           "subregions":[
                              {
                                 "name":"Arizona",
                                 "travelDistance":818486183.9,
                                 "travelDuration":22151,
                                 "travelDurationTraffic":22151
                              },
                              {
                                 "name":"New Mexico",
                                 "travelDistance":1019336643.92,
                                 "travelDuration":19460,
                                 "travelDurationTraffic":19460
                              },
                              {
                                 "name":"Colorado",
                                 "tollDistance":11959005.54,
                                 "travelDistance":702204931.54,
                                 "travelDuration":14428,
                                 "travelDurationTraffic":14428
                              }
                           ],
                           "tollDistance":11959005.54,
                           "travelDistance":2540027759.36,
                           "travelDuration":56038,
                           "travelDurationTraffic":56038
                        }
                     ]
```

What am I looking at here? The travelDistance in the primary resources array is correctly showing 980 miles:

```
"trafficCongestion":"None",
           "trafficDataUsed":"None",
           "travelDistance":980.715076,
           "travelDuration":56038,
           "travelDurationTraffic":57776,
           "travelMode":"Truck"
```

For this route, there should be 130 miles in Arizona, and 550 miles in New Mexico, and 300 for Colorado (+/- 40ish miles here or there depending on engine and settings).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen that before. I've sent this thread to the engineering team to investigate. I also can't figure out for the life of me what those units are. Will update this post with any updates I hear.

**Update**

That team recently noticed this issue as well and are investigating a fix. They plan to have this fixed in production by end of next week.

**Update 2**

The Bing Maps team also asks that you direct technical support related questions to the Microsoft Q&A forums. The StackOverflow community often closes this type of questions as it's not meant to be a support channel. Here is the main technical forum for Microsoft enterprise mapping products: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-maps.html

Comment: That's excellent news! We are very serious in expanding our mileage interface to Bing, but that was giving us a major headache. Thanks!